# Write app.yaml libraries directive has been error

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

I use the the google provided worldcount program. (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/dataprocessing/helloworld?hl=en)
There are no errors in the compiled.

But add the following to `app.yaml`:

```
libraries:
- Name: numpy
  version: "1.6.1"
```

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 1536, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 1530, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 1101, in __call__
    handler = self.handler(request, response)

TypeError: __init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

I don't know why? please give me a hand. thanks

My code from https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/dataprocessing/helloworld?hl=zh-tw#Downloading_the_Sample_Application

It's google provided code.
I just add the following to `app.yaml`:

```
libraries:
- Name: numpy
  version: "1.6.1"
```

This is my app.yaml

```
application: continue-tset
version: 20
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: no

handlers:

- url: /favicon.ico
  static_dir: static/images

- url: /mapreduce/pipeline/images
  static_dir: mapreduce/lib/pipeline/ui/images

- url: /static/js/custom.js
  static_files: static/js/custom.js
  upload: static/js/custom.js

- url: /mapreduce(/.*)?
  script: mapreduce/main.py

- url: .*
  script: main.py
  login: required

- url: /.*
  script: main.app


libraries:
- Name: numpy
  version: "1.6.1"
```

give me a hand. thanks.

Comment: Before digging a bit deeper, have you tried lowercasing `Name`?

Comment: Also, what else have you tried?

Comment: This is due to a mismatch between your URL routing and your handlers; nothing to do with the libraries directive. You need to show us the rest of your code.

Comment: My code from to https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/dataprocessing/helloworld?hl=zh-tw#Downloading_the_Sample_Application